# Unit testing custom React Hook with window resize event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I'm trying to unit test a simple custom hook, `getWindowWidth()`, but I can not get the window in Enzyme to resize.

I'm using enzyme to mount a component that uses the hook, setting the width of the window object, forcing a re-render, yet the window width never changes.

Here is the hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function getWindowWidth() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  });

  return width;
}
```

and here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import getWindowWidth from './getWindowWidth';

// simulate window resize
function fireResize(width) {
  window.innerWidth = width;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
}
// Test component that uses the Hook
function EffecfulComponent() {
  const viewport = getWindowWidth()
  return <span>{viewport}</span>
}

test('should show updated window width', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<EffecfulComponent />)
  expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('1024');
  fireResize(320);
  wrapper.update();
  expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('320');
});
```

I expected the window to resize to 320, but it stays at 1024 (the default).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Jest makes use of jsdom which doesn’t provide the window object. You need to mock in order to test it.